# python mpl_toolkits installation issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

After command `pip install mpl_toolkits` I receive next error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mpl_toolkits (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for mpl_toolkits

I tried to google, but nothing helps. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

*It is not on PyPI and you should not be installing it via `pip`*. If you have `matplotlib` installed, you should be able to import `mpl_toolkits` directly:

```
$ pip install --upgrade matplotlib
...

$ python
>>> import mpl_toolkits
>>>
```

Comment: Did not work for me, I am using Python27. Any see the same issue.

Comment: @user3303020 I am also on python 2.7 and see the same problem

Answer (score 19):

It doesn't work on *Ubuntu 16.04*, it seems that some libraries have been forgotten in the python installation package on this one. You should use package manager instead.

### Solution

Uninstall *matplotlib* from *pip* then install it again with *apt-get*

**python 2:**

```
sudo pip uninstall matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

**python 3:**

```
sudo pip3 uninstall matplotlib
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

Answer (score 9):

if anyone has a problem on Mac, can try this

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib --ignore-installed six
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
pip install basemap
```

Comment: This also worked for me, I didn't actually have to import just `mpl_toolkits` but basemap which is included in this library, likely the issue is that (certain version) `matplotlib` installs do not contain the basemap just by itself, you need to further install basemap.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment due to the lack of reputation, but if you are on arch linux, you should be able to find the corresponding libraries on the arch repositories directly. For example for `mpl_toolkits.basemap`:

```
pacman -S python-basemap
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `pip install mpl_toolkits.clifford`