# ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python program and am trying to plot something using the mplot3d from mpl toolkits,  but whenever I try to import the Axes3D from mpl_toolkits `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D`
 I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named mpl_toolkits`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python mpl\_toolkits installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661119/python-mpl-toolkits-installation-issue)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by running the following imports in the following order:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import mpl_toolkits

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

Note: This only worked for me on python3. So first, I had to install python3 and pip3. Then I did "pip3 install matplotlib" in Terminal. If you already have matplotlib then try "pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib"

Comment: ```pip3 install --upgrade matplotlib``` worked for me