# No module named mpl_toolkits python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pip

I am trying to run an old python script (v2.7) which uses the following statement

```
import mpl_toolkits
```

however this gives an error: **No module named mpl_toolkits**. Some more background information and things I've already tried:

1. I'm running macOS Catalina.
2. Checking my `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` directory I find the mpl_toolkits folder is there.
3. I added `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to my `$PYTHONPATH` variable so that it displays when I type `sys.path` into python.
4. I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling and upgrading matplotlib as per this stackoverflow: [python mpl_toolkits installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661119/python-mpl-toolkits-installation-issue)
5. `pip install mpl_toolkits` results in the following error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.mpl_toolkits (from versions: )
   No matching distribution found for matplotlib.mpl_toolkits
6. I have tried this on the python2.7 interpreter shipped with macOS and a version downloaded with brew with no success.

Pretty stumped as to why this isn't working especially since the module already exists and the path to that module is in my system path. Any help and or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be solved using `pip install matplotlib`

Comment: @Anwarvic this does not solve the problem. It is already installed - I get "Requirement already satisfied" when I run this. I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling matplotlib to no effect

Comment: Do you use any type of virtual environment?

Comment: No I'm just running the commands through the terminal.

Comment: Open `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and see if there is a folder named `mpl_toolkits`

Comment: yes mpl_toolkits exists there

Comment: what is the result of running `which python`?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: Try out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47577975/5612363

Comment: I couldn't  install apt-get as I am on a mac. I installed macports instead and ran sudo port install py27-matplotlib. I then switched to this version of python using sudo select --set python2 python27. Now it works. Still not sure why this all happened but at least it works now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I don't know either... I'm glad you find this issue :)